A variation of Mueller's formula
According to here, if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ then
$$\sum_{k=1}^{x}f(k)$$
which is only defined for positive integer $x$, can be extended to the whole complex plane through this formula:
$$\mathop{\to\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum}\limits_{k=1}^{x}f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}f(k)-f(x+k)$$
For example, when $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then
$$\mathop{\to\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum}\limits_{k=1}^{x}\frac{1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{x+k}$$
And this is defined for all $x$ except at the negative integers.
Question: when $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ but $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=0$ then how does one extend $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{x}f(k)$ with $\mathop{\to\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sum}\limits_{k=1}^{x}f(k)$?
